# undefined variable under jquery payload

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to post some data to an API but I'm struggling with javascript.

```
function pushData() {
  let rawdata;
  $.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
  });
  $.getJSON('https://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self', function(result) {
    result = rawdata;
  })
  console.log(rawdata);

  let message = {
    "ip": rawdata.ipAddress,
    "country": rawdata.countryName,
    "city": rawdata.city
  };

  console.log(message);

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/get",
    headers: {},
    /*         crossDomain: true,
     */
    type: "GET",
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
  })
}
$.ajax({
  url: "https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/post",
  crossDomain: true,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(message),
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("error pushing data");
  }
})
```

I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined` although I think that `message` is a global variable, so it should be called successfully on the payload? What I'm I doing wrong here?

Thanks to anyone for his reply in advance, I'm just trying to write a quick script for my API here.

Comment: `result = rawdata;` is backwards, it should be `rawdata = result;`

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated, you should learn to use asynchronous code.

Comment: `message` is not a global variable. It's local to the `pushData()` function.

Comment: Is the `result` from the GET request useful? It does not seem to be used. -- Order of execution **1)** `pushData` is declared. **2)** The POST ajax request is sent out. -- Unclear what calls the `pushData` function.

Comment: @Barmar I messed up the variable when trying to sanitize the code to post it here.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette this script is called with ` <body class="w3-light-grey" onload="pushData()"> `, and I'm just using both requests (GET & POST) as a draft for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message` is a local variable in the `pushData()` function, not a global variable. But even if it were global, you'd have to call the function before the second `$.ajax()` call.

Move the second AJAX call inside the function so you can access the variable. And embrace asynchrony, don't fight it with `async: false`. Nest the successive AJAX calls inside the callback function of the previous one.

```js
function pushData() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self', function(rawData) {
    console.log(rawdata);

    let message = {
      "ip": rawdata.ipAddress,
      "country": rawdata.countryName,
      "city": rawdata.city
    };

    console.log(message);

    $.ajax({
          url: "https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/get",
          headers: {},
          /*         crossDomain: true,
           */
          type: "GET",
          success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/post",
              crossDomain: true,
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              data: JSON.stringify(message),
              success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
              },
              error: function() {
                console.log("error pushing data");
              }
            })
          });
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("error");
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been fighting with this code to work, can't believe it's caused by misplaced curly brackets. I appreciate the other clarification. I just picked up JS for this quick work, and I know that the code isn't optimized yet (I decide to fall back for now to sync calls after getting some error)